# Is there a way to run for loop in a mongoose schema method?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I want to run the following for loop for the length of the array but all it does is to add one by one.

Any idea?

```
EndorsedSkillSchema.methods = {
  async userEndorsedSkill(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const skill = await Skill.findOne({ _id: arr[i]._id });

      const s = skill.toJSON();

      this.skills.push(arr[i]._id);
      await this.save();
      pubsub.publish(SKILL_ENDORSED, { [SKILL_ENDORSED]: { ...s } });
      return {
        endorsed: true,
        ...s
      };
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Why not you use `Promise.all()` for such kind of things.

Comment: @NeelRathod because I have to find each each skill separately

Comment: In this case you need to take id's array and make one query for find whole id's data then loop on it

Answer (score 1):

You could use `find()` and `{$in: ids}`

```
 const arr = [{_id:1},{_id:2},{_id:3}];

 const ids = arr.map(e=>e._id);

 Skill.find({_id: {$in: ids}}, function(err, result){
    //callback here maybe .insertMany()
 });
```

Comment: Using this you have only one query for getting results which makes your execution time shorter compare to find with separate queries